# Including Dependencies That Target .NET 4.x in Travis While Using Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, travis-ci

I am using the Unity Game Engine for a school project. I use: https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity to download Nuget Packages, as Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager doesn't play well when Unity regenerates the .sln file.

One of the packages I use is https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions

Locally, this works fine, however, when just having this dll as part of my project causes the Travis build to fail. I am unsure of the exact cause but I suspect it has to do with the build not being able to target the corect framework, as Unity by default targets .NET 3.5.

Is there a way that I can debug my build to find the target version or manually set the target version to .NET 4.0?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the Scripting Runtime Version in Unity to `.Net 4.6` in the project settings

Go to the `PlayerSettings`

[image]

and there under `Other Settings`
switch `Scripting Runtime Version` to `Experimental (.Net 4.6 Equivalent)`

[image]

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRuntimeUpgrade.html

Comment: Locally, everything works fine. After more debugging, I realized that the build simply isn't recognizing the references. Not sure why.